# Recursively find the nth order derivative with autograd grad()

Tags: python, recursion, derivative

I am trying to find the nth derivative of a function using the grad function from the autograd library. grad(x) gives the 1st order derivative, but it doesn't allow a variable to find let's say the 3rd order derivative etc. Is there a way I might be able to do this recursively so the user can ender the derivative order they want to see?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from autograd import grad
import autograd.numpy as np


# a named Python function
g = lambda w: w**2

w_vals = np.linspace(-5,5,200)
nabla_g = grad(g)   #A function here that can find the nth derivative
# evaluate gradient over input range
g_vals = [g(v) for v in w_vals]
grad_vals = [nabla_g(v) for v in w_vals]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite simple. You should nest your grad function

```
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from autograd import grad
import autograd.numpy as np

def my_grad(fun, ord):
    for i in range(ord):
        fun = grad(fun)
    return fun

# a named Python function
g = lambda w: w**3

# derivative x^3 = 3x^2
# derivative 3x^2 = 6x
# derivative 6x = 6
w_vals = np.linspace(-5,5,200)
nabla_g = my_grad(g, 3)   # recursive call to grad lead to 3° derivative
g_vals = [g(v) for v in w_vals]
grad_vals = [nabla_g(v) for v in w_vals]
print(grad_vals) #should output 6 for every input
```

I also developed the recursive version of my_grad:

```
def my_grad(fun, ord):
    if ord == 0:
       return fun
    return my_grad(grad(fun), ord-1)
```

Comment: The user needs to be able to enter the derivative order they want to see. So def dev_order(order):

Comment: @IdrisSunmola I updated the answer with the function you need.

Comment: @IdrisSunmola you're welcome! Don't forget to accept the best answer :)